# Visual Studio 2017 build of project doesn't require references. New vs Old project file syntax

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

Two versions of project files seem to cause VS2017 (MSBUILD 15.0) builds to behave differently.  In the first project file case (newer style?), i don't actually have to add all the dependencies.  Normally in a code file, when you do "using something", you have to include a reference to "something" in the project.  But NOT with this **Project File 1** style below.  I can include via "using" a reference in my code file to something that is NOT in the project's references.  Visual Studio will build it fine.  But then when i run a command line msbuild, the missing reference causes a build failure.  This failure is the traditional thing i would also get in Visual Studio when using the second type of **Project File 2**.   Ie. the traditional "sorry, but if you are 'using' something you need a reference in your project".  Visual Studio 101 since what ... 2003?

So, Visual Studio is somehow being smarter.  In a way that i think breaks the basic effing rules here, but whatever.

When i look at the diagnostic (ie. most detailed) output of the builds, it is clear that there are some differences. For one, the output format is different (the new style formats things a bit better with pseudo-tabs between variables and values).   It also clearly has slightly different environment/whatever variables.  Just for example, it has slightly different values for the "Resolve*" set of values. I am just assuming that VS is setting some environment variables (I can't see any command line parms in the output) that is causing msbuild to behave differently.  All the msbuild tools and VS version stuff looks the same.

So, how do i make VS and msbuild act the same?  Is there a particular environment variable or command line argument to get msbuild to be as "smart" as VS?  Or to tell VS to behave according to the traditional rule?  Or do i have to go redo all my project files to be the older version?

**Project File 1**: (newer style?)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net4.6.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="blah" />
```

**Project File 2**: (traditional/older style)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
...snip...
ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="blah2">
      <Project>{GUID SNIPPED}</Project>
      <Name>blahs</Name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  It is the different project files.  The newer ones with this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

Causes VS to do a restore that generates these

PS F:\Depots\blah\Source\obj> ls

```
Debug
project.assets.json
blah.csproj.nuget.cache
blah.csproj.nuget.g.props
blah.csproj.nuget.g.targets
```

That restore magically gets all the DLL’s into the target folder so the build works.

In a new/fresh, pre-VS build, that stuff is not there and msbuild fails.